# Edit a node in the settings tray?

Tags: nodes, 9

I am looking at this page in the [Drupal docs for the Settings Tray](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/settings_tray/using-the-settings-tray) and wondering if this can be used to edit the current node you are looking at, similar to this image:

[image]

Is there a way to edit all of the nodes fields from one tray? Is it expected that you would use QuickEdit (which is being discussed as being [removed from core](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3222947)) to do this? What if there are fields that are not visible but you still want to edit them? Essentially, so folks can edit what they see without going to the traditional node edit form (including url alias, published date, meta tags, etc).

It looks like Acquia Site Studio makes use of the tray on both sides of the screen to do numerous edits and additions:

[image]